# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi k}4)}{k!\sqrt{2^k}}\pi^k=\sqrt{e^\pi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi k}4)}{k!\sqrt{2^k}}\pi^k=\sqrt{e^\pi}$$

Prove that the value of lhs is equal to given value of rhs side. Help me with this doubt I am unable to find out what to do in this question

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). It’s better to show your attempt in the post. What progress did you achieve? Where were you “stuck”? Please refrain from using pictures. There are [different reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/1273570) for that, for example, the search function doesn’t see them. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem),
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).
Furthermore, try to avoid expressions like "doubt", "urgent help", "I am unable" etc. Use mathematical terms instead.

Answer (score 1):

The $k!$ and the $k$th power terms should remind you of Taylor series of $e^x$. The only obstacle is the $\sin(\frac{\pi k}{4})$ term, but it can be easily written as a power function. $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, so we can simply write it as $\text{Im} (e^{i\frac{\pi k}{4}})$.

So the sum becomes $$lhs=\text{Im} \sum\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi k}{4}}\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}\right)^k}{k!}=\text{Im}\sum\frac{\left(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}\right)^k}{k!}$$

$e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}$, so

$$lhs=\text{Im}\sum\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{i\pi}{2}\right)^k}{k!}=\text{Im}(e^{\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{i\pi}{2}})=\text{Im}(ie^\frac{\pi}{2})=e^\frac{\pi}{2}=\sqrt{e^\pi}=rhs.$$

Comment: Correct - but I and others in the community would rather you did not rush to answer pure "do this" questions where the OP shows no work of their own. See the comments on the question.

Comment: @EthanBolker Umm, I never thought about that. Sure, I'll take that into consideration in the future! Thanks.